# How to change theme of python idle

Tags: python, themes, idle

Add the lines below to : Ubuntu(~/.idlerc/config-highlight.cfg)

what is that mean? i can't find that location, can anyone explain reallllly detaily?

Comment: It refers to a file in a hidden directory in your home directory. could you give the link?

Answer (score 1):

here is the detailed answer from crokodyll.blogspot

[image]